# Azure Service Bus - Long running task throws Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException

Tags: c#, azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

We are getting the following exception when executing a long running task in our service bus subscriber.

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException: The lock supplied
>   is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been
>   removed from the queue.

The long-running task does several things including reading 4.5M records from the database, building an Excel document *(using OpenXml)* with multiple sheets *(~1M records per sheet)*, updating a few entities in the database, etc. It's all wrapped inside one method of a service, and that's the only method exposed to the subscriber.

Since this task takes longer than the message is locked for, the message is released to the queue. The subscriber picks it up and starts working on it again. When the first call to the task is finished, we make the following call which immediately throws the exception:

`await client.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)`

We'd like to successfully renew the message lock before it is released back to the queue. We've added an alternative logic using a timer to execute `await client.RenewLockAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)` before the message is released based on the value of `message.SystemProperties.LockedUntilUtc`. This seems to work correctly and effectively if we mimic the task with a `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(2))`, for example, but with the actual call `await internalService.ExportReport()`, the renew doesn't seem to be effective. The message lock release seems to happen at the 5 minute mark always. We've registered our client's `OperationTimeout` and `ServisceBusConnection.OperationTimeout` with `TimeSpan.FromHours(10)`, but that doesn't seem to have an effect on the message lock timeout.

Our core libraries target *netstandard2.0*, our application targets *netcoreapp2.2* and we're using *Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v4.0.0*.

Can anyone out there give us some suggestions on how better approach this case, or any long-running task in general?

Comment: Before I answer, just to be sure, are you invoking `client.RenewLockAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)` using the **same** client used to receive the message?

Comment: That is correct, @SeanFeldman.

Comment: Using the same client should do it so something is definitely off. Would you be able to share a simple repro (on GitHub or similar)?

Comment: I'll try, Sean. The code is heavily abstracted and it would be difficult to do it, but I'll try and see if I can give you a concrete example. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Ripping out abstractions is not trivial though needed to isolate the problem. Once you have it, post the link and I’ll be happy to look into it.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Hi @SeanFeldman. Apologies for the delay in my response. Unfortunately, I had to move on to other projects and eventually to another company. I'm not sure how the team got around this particular issue. I know it was an edge case in our environment since all other consumers were processing the messages correctly and in a timely manner. Many thanks for your help on this, -Ivan.

Comment: @Ivan you should've provided an answer because now this question just leads to a dead end with no possible solution which is not quite helpful to the community.